# How can I store and access files from Azure WebSites as regular file names?

Tags: azure, file-io, azure-web-app-service

I have a web application that I'm exploring how to migrate to Azure. I would prefer Azure Websites, or a WebRole, instead of a full blown Azure VM if possible.

One challenge is that this web application uses a set of third party DLL files, which need read access to a set of reference files. These reference files are quite large -- around 7GB -- across ~150 files. The DLL's need to be able to access these files using "normal" file names or UNC paths. So I think this would rule out Azure BLOB storage since that appears to only support REST operations.

The 7GB reference files are updated monthly.

I realize that I could create a VM on Azure, and copy these files to each VM instance. However I'm trying to avoid the administrative overhead associated with the full blown VM, and IIS management.

Also, it would appear that there should be some method to upload the reference files once, and have shared access to all WebSites that are running.

Any help and advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's possible without VM. What you can try. Create a Cloud services Web Role, which will simplify your life with the IIS management, and enable RDP to it, then copy your files using a remote desktop connection.

Honestly, I'd go with VM.

Comment: Copying files to a Web Role instance is only going to lead to a life of frustration, since the contents of your file-copy will disappear the moment the role instance has trouble (e.g. local storage disk crashes, or vm is moved to a different physical host).

Answer (score 0):

Azure websites, in Standard mode which means your site running on it's own dedicated VM, gives you 50GB for your site of storage.

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/